# Trying to place text on specific coordinate?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Using tikz, I would like to place a math symbol directly onto a coordinate. I am unsure of how to do this, since it does not appear that I can use the \coordinate command as you need to label it either left or right. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
\coordinate [label=center:$...$] (a) at (x,y);
```

but for your case it sounds more natural to use

```
\node at (x,y) {$...$};
```

Comment: Thanks!  Much appreciated